# TFS 2015 can't see other user's pending changes on branch

Tags: tfs, branch, tfs-2015, tfvc

MS Team Foundation Server 2015, with the native TFS SCM:

On the main branch, every user can see pending changes from every other user.

I branched off a branch from the main branch with several check-ins in the past already. I'm currently having locally modified files on that branch and see them as pending changes in Source Control Explorer. However another colleague does not see these pending changes. Why?

(He can see pending changes on the main trunk just fine like everyone else.)

Is it a property of the branch that i need to set somewhere?

Comment: Have checked if your colleague has permission on the new branch? If yes, has he permission to read, check in, label, lock, merge, pend a change in server workspace?

Comment: Why would you expect someone else to be able to see your pending changes? Pending changes are only visible to the person that created them -- nothing about pending changes exists on the server, they are entirely local.

Comment: @Daniel Mann: Well, as i said, we do see them all on the main trunk.

Comment: @Rodrigo Werlang: Where to check that? Will have a look back at work tomorrow. I just created the branch from the main trunk. So shouldn't the same permission get carried over?

Comment: @Scrontch Are the Main and Branch in the same workspace?

Comment: @Scrontch, to check it you have to go to the project Settings -> Version Control, select your branch to see the permissions

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether you have mapped the Main and Branch in the same workspace. And check whether you are using server workspace.